# Navigation bar height as in iMessage (iOS 10)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, navigationbar

How do I make the increase of the navigation bar height in iMessage (iOS 10), with animation, and when this controller is hidden, then also with the animation return the previous height?

I read several articles, I can share them here, but they do not give such an effect as in iMessage (iOS 10). Thank you.

**Update:** Or how to track that the `UIViewController` is hiding on the point to make a smooth animation, since we get a `viewWillDisappear` call that the controller starts hiding, but it also may be that the user hides it with a slow gesture and therefore it is necessary to reduce the `NavigationBar` height relative to the percentage of how much the current controller already hidden. How is it better to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're able to change the navigation bar its height with an animation by subclassing it and creating a property for the height (barHeight) and animating it after setting the value.

**Swift 3**

```
final class CustomHeightNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

var navigationItemsOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 10) { // default offset (below statusbar)
    didSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { [weak self] in
            self?.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}

var barHeight: CGFloat = 60 { // default height
    didSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { [weak self] in
            self?.sizeToFit()
            self?.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: barHeight)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    frame.origin = navigationItemsOffset

    subviews.forEach { (subview) in
        subview.center.y = center.y
    }
}
```

After creating the subclass you've to set it as a custom class for your navigation bar in the storyboard, which is located in the navigation controller.

[image]

Now you're able to animate the height of the navigation bar within a view controller by changing the value of the barHeight property.

**Swift 3**

```
var navigationBar: CustomHeightNavigationBar? {
    guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar as? CustomHeightNavigationBar else {
        return nil
    }
    return navigationBar
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let navigationBar = navigationBar {
        navigationBar.barHeight = 60
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let navigationBar = navigationBar {
        navigationBar.barHeight = 44
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:
In order to animate the height of the bar at the exact same time with the transition, you have to implement this method on `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`

```
        self.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
        let height: CGFloat = 80 //any size you want
        let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: height)

    }, completion: { (context) in
        //Any code you may want to add after the transition
    })
```